# Better way to download files that are checked in grid view

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a grid view with a column of check boxes and then several columns of data. When one row is selected, its corresponding image is displayed. Any row can be checked without being selected and when the download button is clicked, all the images with their corresponding rows checked should be downloaded. Right now I have a for loop going through every row and finding the checkbox and seeing if it is checked for not, and it takes way too long. Is there a way to access the corresponding row's data when the checkbox is checked?

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gv1.Rows
  Dim chkBox As CheckBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("cBox"), CheckBox)
  If chkBox.Checked Then
    Dim full = row.Cells(1).Text & "B" & row.Cells(3).Text
    IO.File.Copy(serv & full & ".TIF", Path.Combine(temp, full & ".TIF"), True)
  End If
Next
```

Comment: If the grid is data bound, can't you check the data instead? See [GridView Class / Binding to Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8#binding-to-data)

Comment: Probably the actual loop and checkbox check is very fast. The slow part would just be all the file copy.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The problem is figuring out which row the checked check-boxes are in without looping through every row.

Comment: @EJC, I know, but if you use data binding, then edits in the grid will automatically update the data (e.g. being in a `List<MyDataClass>`). So instead of looping rows and cells and controls, you could just loop the list and check the corresponding `bool` property. You end up in a one-liner: `var selected = myList.Where(d => d.IsSelected);` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me, very efficient. It was the IO copy that was taking too long.

```
Using zip As New ZipFile()
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary
        zip.AddDirectoryByName("Drawings")
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gv1.Rows
            If TryCast(row.FindControl("cBox"), CheckBox).Checked Then
                found = True
                Dim filepath = serv & row.Cells(1).Text & "B" & row.Cells(3).Text & ".TIF"
                zip.AddFile(filepath, "Drawings")
            End If
        Next
        If found Then
            Response.Clear()
            Response.BufferOutput = False
            Dim zipname As String = [String].Format("Drawings_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss"))
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipname)
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream)
            Response.End()
        Else
            reSetup()
        End If
    End Using
```